# How to handle soap:mustUnderstand="1" in webservice

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

In an incoming soap request there is a soap:mustUnderstand="1" element in soap header ,how can I handle this in my web service . If soap:mustUnderstand="1"  it throws exception when it is 0 (soap:mustUnderstand="0") it runs as expected .

this is my partial soap request is like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header xmlns="http://www.xxxxxxx/zzzzz-msg/schema/msg-header-1_0.xsd">
          <MessageHeader ResponseRequested="true" version="1.0" Terminate="true" Reverse="true" id="0002P559C1" soap:mustUnderstand="1">

   .......
   ......
```

I am using Apache CXF for web service .

Answer (score 1):

Your service should explicitly tell CXF that the given header has been understood and processed.

One way of doing it is registering a subclass of `SOAPHandler` responsible for actual processing of you header. In that interface it's important to implement method `Set<QName> getHeaders()` and return a set of headers' names that your handler takes care about.

CXF will then treat all those headers as **understood**

Example:

in Spring context XML:

```
<jaxws:endpoint ...>
    <jaxws:handlers>
        <bean class="example.MySOAPHandler" />
    </jaxws:handlers>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

in Java code:

```
public class MySOAPHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    public static final String MY_NS_URI = "http://www.xxxxxxx/zzzzz-msg/schema/msg-header-1_0.xsd";
    public static final String MY_HEADER_NAME = "MessageHeader";

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        // This will tell CXF that the following headers are UNDERSTOOD
        return Collections.singleton(new QName(MY_NS_URI, MY_HEADER_NAME));
    }

    // other handler methods here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If a header block is annotated with mustUnderstand="1" and the
>   receiver wasn't designed to support the given header, the message
>   shouldn't be processed and a Fault should be returned to the sender
>   (with a soap:MustUnderstand status code). When mustUnderstand="0" or
>   the mustUnderstand attribute isn't present, the receiver can ignore
>   those headers and continue processing. The mustUnderstand attribute
>   plays a central role in the overall SOAP processing model.

For details kindly refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995800.aspx)

Comment: As I have created that web service how can I handle mustUnderstand="1" in my web service . I am using Apache CXF for building web service

Comment: What do you mean by handling ?@Ashok